# Error using scipy.optimize nonlinear solvers

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, scipy, nonlinear-functions

I am trying to solve a set of M simultaneous eqns with M variables. I input a M X 2 matrix in as an initial guess to my function and it returns a M X 2 matrix, where each entry would equal zero if my guess was correct. Thus my function can be represented as `f_k(u1,u2,...uN) = 0` for `k=1,2,...N`. Below is the code for my function, (for simplicities sake I have left out the modules that go with this code, i.e. p. or phi. for instance. I was more wondering if anyone else has had this error before)

```
    M = len(p.x_lat)

def main(u_A):

    ## unpack u_A

    u_P = u_total[:,0]
    u_W = u_total[:,1]

    ## calculate phi_A for all monomeric species

    G_W = exp(-u_W)

    phi_W = zeros(M)
    phi_W[1:] = p.phi_Wb * G_W[1:]

    ## calculate phi_A for all polymeric species

    G_P = exp(-u_P)
    G_P[0] = 0.
    G_fwd = phi.fwd_propagator(G_P,p.Np,0)  #(function that takes G_P and propagates outward)
    G_bkwd = phi.bkwd_propagator(G_P,p.Np,0) #(function that takes G_P and propagates inward)

    phi_P = phi.phi_P(G_fwd,G_bkwd,p.norm_graft_density,p.Np)  #(function that takes the two   propagators and combines them to calculate a segment density at each point)

    ## calculate u_A components

    u_intW = en.u_int_AB(p.chi_PW,phi_P,p.phi_Pb) + en.u_int_AB(p.chi_SW,p.phi_S,p.phi_Sb) #(fxn that calculates new potential from the new segment densities)
    u_intW[0] = 0.
    u_Wprime = u_W - u_intW

    u_intP = en.u_int_AB(p.chi_PW,phi_W,p.phi_Wb) + en.u_int_AB(p.chi_PS,p.phi_S,p.phi_Sb) #(fxn that calculates new potential from the new segment densities)
    u_intP[0] = 0.
    u_Pprime = u_P - u_intP

    ## calculate f_A

    phi_total = p.phi_S + phi_W + phi_P
    u_prime = 0.5 * (u_Wprime + u_Pprime)

    f_total = zeros( (M, 2) )
    f_total[:,0] = 1. - 1./phi_total + u_prime - u_Wprime
    f_total[:,1] = 1. - 1./phi_total + u_prime - u_Pprime

    return f_total
```

I researched ways of solving nonlinear equations such as this one using python. I came across the `scipy.optimize library` with the several options for solvers http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.13.0/reference/optimize.nonlin.html. I first tried to use the `newton_krylov` solver and received the following error message:

> `ValueError: Jacobian inversion yielded zero vector. This indicates a bug in the Jacobian approximation.`

I also tried `broyden1` solver and it never converged but simply stayed stagnant. Code for implementation of both below:

```
    sol = newton_krylov(main, guess, verbose=1, f_tol=10e-7)  
    sol = broyden1(main, guess, verbose=1, f_tol=10e-7)
```

My initial guess is given below here:

```
   ## first guess of u_A(x)

    u_P = zeros(M)
    u_P[1] = -0.0001  
    u_P[M-1] = 0.0001

    u_W = zeros(M)
    u_W[1] = 0.0001
    u_W[M-1] = -0.0001

    u_total = zeros( (M,2) )
    u_total[:,0] = u_P
    u_total[:,1] = u_W
    guess = u_total
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is your problem like? Perhaps there are very flat regions in the objective function? Or perhaps your initial guess is not good enough (in which case you google for continuation methods)? You can try to use the keyword argument `line_search='wolfe'` to tell the solver to use a more conservative line search so that it doesn't venture to the flat parts. There are also problems that are not solvable in practice with inexact newton methods, and if yours is one of them, you're out of luck with these solvers.

Comment: It's a diffusion type problem. I did try the `line_search='wolfe'` to no avail unfortunately. It turns out that during the iterations my exponential was getting too large, and overflow was occurring during the propagation step in `Gfwd` above. I scaled it down using a normalization factor. Thanks so much for your help though!